# Replace the row values in one group with the value from a similar group if conditions on rows are met data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that looks like the below, grouped by id and type.

If the sample size is zero in period i and i is not equal to 1, I would like to replace the value of the 'calculation' column for that row with the product of 'calculation' from that group in period i -1 and 'mov' from a similar group in period i. What i mean by similar is it would take mov from either id + 1 or id - 1, with type the same and period = i.

The choice of similar id is not that important, i.e. it could default to id -1 and if that id is not available use id + 1.

```
       id samplesize type calculation        mov period
 1: 10603         15    1   1.1884602 -1.0236411      1
 2: 10603        105    1  -1.0809550 -1.1311796      2
 3: 10603        111    1   0.2358396 -0.5401774      3
 4: 10603        115    1   0.7322120  0.1195699      4
 5: 10603        113    1  -0.9727271 -0.4505766      5
 6: 10603        113    1   0.3711188  0.8088049      6
 7: 10604          0    1  -0.3795332 -0.2963887      1
 8: 10604          0    1   0.2203382  0.6357711      2
 9: 10604         50    1  -0.5731365 -0.6450074      3
10: 10604         54    1   0.3233726  0.3395729      4
11: 10604         53    1   0.2111071 -1.2167302      5
12: 10604         52    1   0.6702184  0.9840893      6
```

So the resulting data table would like:

```
       id samplesize type calculation        mov period
 1: 10603         15    1   1.1884602 -1.0236411      1
 2: 10603        105    1  -1.0809550 -1.1311796      2
 3: 10603        111    1   0.2358396 -0.5401774      3
 4: 10603        115    1   0.7322120  0.1195699      4
 5: 10603        113    1  -0.9727271 -0.4505766      5
 6: 10603        113    1   0.3711188  0.8088049      6
 7: 10604          0    1  -0.3795332 -0.2963887      1
 8: 10604          0    1   0.4293202  0.6357711      2
 9: 10604         50    1  -0.5731365 -0.6450074      3
10: 10604         54    1   0.3233726  0.3395729      4
11: 10604         53    1   0.2111071 -1.2167302      5
12: 10604         52    1   0.6702184  0.9840893      6
```

Note the actual data has 277 groups and 53 periods per group so some sort of loop might be a bit slow. Also one of id + 1 or id - 1 would always be available, but both may not always be available.

```
dput(test)

structure(list(id = c(10603L, 10603L, 10603L, 10603L, 10603L, 
10603L, 10604L, 10604L, 10604L, 10604L, 10604L, 10604L), samplesize = c(15L, 
105L, 111L, 115L, 113L, 113L, 0L, 0L, 50L, 54L, 53L, 52L), type = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), calculation = c(1.18846016375132, 
-1.08095498270142, 0.235839633282068, 0.732211968154904, -0.972727101272223, 
0.371118753750896, -0.379533157458354, 0.220338197196561, -0.573136536559793, 
0.323372576946197, 0.21110710320273, 0.670218361977238), mov = c(-1.02364112036935, 
-1.13117955732701, -0.540177404426532, 0.119569869902065, -0.450576581730733, 
0.808804864876457, -0.296388732980522, 0.635771118121571, -0.645007399711979, 
0.339572874056865, -1.21673020152297, 0.984089256133723), period = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000023ad4ad1ef0>)
```

I tried to use an ifelse statement but it just returns NA

```
test <- test[period != 1, calculation := ifelse(samplesize == 0,
                                                calculation[(period == period - 1)] * mov[id == id-1], 
                                                calculation), by = "type"]

      id samplesize type calculation        mov period
 1: 10603         15    1   1.1884602 -1.0236411      1
 2: 10603        105    1  -1.0809550 -1.1311796      2
 3: 10603        111    1   0.2358396 -0.5401774      3
 4: 10603        115    1   0.7322120  0.1195699      4
 5: 10603        113    1  -0.9727271 -0.4505766      5
 6: 10603        113    1   0.3711188  0.8088049      6
 7: 10604          0    1  -0.3795332 -0.2963887      1
 8: 10604          0    1          NA  0.6357711      2
 9: 10604         50    1  -0.5731365 -0.6450074      3
10: 10604         54    1   0.3233726  0.3395729      4
11: 10604         53    1   0.2111071 -1.2167302      5
12: 10604         52    1   0.6702184  0.9840893      6
```

Answer (score 0):

If `period` variable does not repeat for the same `id` in your data, you could try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dt <- copy(test)[order(period, id)]
dt <- dt[, temp := shift(calculation, type = "lag"), by = c("id")]
dt <- dt[, temp2 := ifelse(samplesize == 0, temp * 
                             ifelse(shift(id, type = "lag") == id - 1, shift(mov, type = "lag"), 
                                    ifelse(shift(id, type = "lead") == id + 1, shift(mov, type = "lead"), NA)),
                           calculation, by = c("period"))]
dt <- dt[period != 1 & samplesize == 0, calculation := temp2] %>% select(-c("temp", "temp2"))
dt <- dt[order(id, period)]
```

Result:

```
       id samplesize type calculation        mov period
 1: 10603         15    1   1.1884602 -1.0236411      1
 2: 10603        105    1  -1.0809550 -1.1311796      2
 3: 10603        111    1   0.2358396 -0.5401774      3
 4: 10603        115    1   0.7322120  0.1195699      4
 5: 10603        113    1  -0.9727271 -0.4505766      5
 6: 10603        113    1   0.3711188  0.8088049      6
 7: 10604          0    1  -0.3795332 -0.2963887      1
 8: 10604          0    1   0.4293201  0.6357711      2
 9: 10604         50    1  -0.5731365 -0.6450074      3
10: 10604         54    1   0.3233726  0.3395729      4
11: 10604         53    1   0.2111071 -1.2167302      5
12: 10604         52    1   0.6702184  0.9840893      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Darmist, reordering the data was the trick, although i also needed to order by type too so it didnt inherit mov from a group where the type was different. Writing it as a case_when statement also makes it a bit more readable.

```
dt <- copy(test)[order(type, period, id)]


dt <- dt[, temp := shift(calculation, type = "lag"), by = c("id")]


dt <- dt[, temp2 := 
           lest::case_when(shift(id, type = "lag") == id - 1 ~ temp * shift(mov, type = "lag"),
                           shift(id, type = "lead") == id + 1 ~ temp * shift(mov, type = "lead")), 
         by = "period"]


dt <- dt[period != 1 & samplesize == 0, calculation := temp2] %>% select(-c("temp", "temp2"))
dt <- dt[order(type, period, id)]
```